# Div блок с диагональными полосками как фон

Tags: html, css, css3

Всем привет! 
Я облазал весь интернет и не смог найти ответ. 
Как сделать DIV блок с диагональными полосками как фон?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mbzebydj/

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  }
body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 49.9%, 
      #1E989C 49.9%, #1E989C 60%, 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%
      ),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      #1E989C 10%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10%
      );
  background-size: 2em 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  font: 40px/2 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!)

Comment: А можно такой вопрос?) Я добавил ваш код и тут все полетело)) Вот как должно выглядеть http://rghost.ru/8vD64sfGx/image.png а вот последствия вашего кода http://jsfiddle.net/mbzebydj/3/